# How do I suppress this warning?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, warnings

How do I make intellij shut up about "Class can be a record" warning?
The quickfixes it suggests are just making the class a record.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#suppress-in-editor ?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Doesn't work,it proceeds to change the class to a record

Comment: Did you press the right arrow to open the submenu with the option to suppress/disable it?

Comment: A @SuppressWarnings would be better to indicate that the class should not be converted into a record. E.g. in Spring, this could give some serious issues with dependency injection.

Comment: @FNL How does one go about suppressing this specific warning? Can't find it anywhere.

Comment: @vintproykt Currently, no \@SuppressWarnings exists for doing it. I guess we should make a proposal for JetBrains to create one for this specific warning.
I am sorry I gave you the impression that I had an answer. I guess the only work-around for now is to disable the warning in IntelliJ like CrazyCoder proposes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since there is no clear `@SuppressWarnings` clause for this, hiding this warning can only be directly configured in your IDE.

In fact, IntelliJ IDEA has a setting just for this.

- In `Settings` window, search for `Inspections "Can be a record"`.
- Switch severity for `Can be a record` inspection to `No highlighting, only fix`.

[image: IntelliJ IDEA Inspections]